# Why are my summed columns doubling in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, with 2 temporary tables I am joining on several columns. If I eliminate the join from this statement and have the same select, each of the tables provides the desired result and the union and grouping works fine. Gives me the same amount of rows as the full query would also.

If I eliminate the union the query produces the expected result as well and the join works fine.

I am joining on mostly time values in each table and the name/other names will match. I have looked at other examples of this same question and I still cannot understand why my values are doubling for s.n,s.r etc.

edit -  I realized this may be confusing but I had to simplify the query for the post, there are different where clauses in each table and that is why they are separated into 2 temp tables. Even more perplexing is if I just divide the final column result by 2 that does not work. Multiplying the average by 2 also is fail.

```sql
WITH s 
(
    c,m,w,q,y,nsb,rgp
) as 
(
    SELECT 
            NAME, 
            Fiscal_Month_Number,
            Fiscal_Week_Of_Quarter,
            quarter,
            year, 
            SUM(N), 
            SUM(P)
        FROM 
            table1
        GROUP BY 
            Fiscal_Month_Number, 
            Fiscal_Week_Of_Quarter, 
            quarter,
            year, 
            NAME
    UNION
    SELECT 
            othername, 
            fiscal_month_number,
            week,
            quarter,
            year,
            SUM(n), 
            SUM(p)
        FROM 
            table2
        GROUP BY 
            othername,
            week,
            year,
            Fiscal_Month_Number,
            quarter
),
p 
(
    c,m,w,q,y,nsb,rgp
) as 
(
    SELECT 
            name,
            Fiscal_Month_Number,
            Fiscal_Week_Of_Quarter,
            quarter,
            year,
            SUM(n),
            SUM(p) 
        FROM
            table1
        GROUP BY 
            Fiscal_Month_Number,
            Fiscal_Week_Of_Quarter,
            quarter,
            year,
            NAME
    UNION
    SELECT 
            othername,
            fiscal_month_number,
            week,
            quarter,
            year,
            SUM(n),
            SUM(p)
        FROM
            table2
        GROUP BY
            OTHERNAME,
            week,
            year,
            Fiscal_Month_Number,
            quarter
)
SELECT 
        s.c,
        s.m,
        s.w,
        s.q,
        s.y,
        SUM(s.n),
        SUM(s.p),
        SUM(p.n),
        SUM(p.p)
    FROM
        s
    JOIN p on
        p.c = s.c 
    AND p.m = s.m
    AND p.w = s.w
    AND s.y = p.y
    AND p.q = s.q
    GROUP BY 
        s.c, 
        s.m, 
        s.w, 
        s.y,
        s.q
```

Comment: I guess I add two more temp tables to regroup since I am using union? Seems like an ridiculously long query... is there a cleaner way?

Comment: It's hard to say without sample data and queries that would show the problem. As you mentioned, your sample queries have two CTEs that are exactly the same so that would come out doubled. instead of doing the join at the bottom can you do a union ``select * from s union select * from p`` and see what you get back? Looking at your data should show you where the problem is coming from. Sounds like it something in the where clauses.